# How to debug a site's page that requires login?

Tags: asp.net, azure, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to figure out how a website that I've had built by a developer in .Net Core works so that I can attempt to take over the project on my own.  I can successfully launch the project into a localhost debug mode,but the problem is the page that I'm trying to debug requires a login first.  So if I launch the program from Visual Studio, the index page loads fine with localhost, then I try to access the protected page via the localhost link, it redirects me to AzureB2C to login, and then it shows me the protected page on the server version and not the localhost version.  I believe the page is protected by the [Authorize] command and has some other logic baked in using User Identity to determine if the user is logged in, and then redirect to login if not. I can't quite figure out how to disable it because I'm literally learning this all from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Follow step 7 of [Register a web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga#register-a-web-application) to add a redirect URI for your local instance.